# Jumping down in HTML when clicking onto a tab

Tags: javascript, html

on http://tinyurl.com/75tx5hn when i click onto "Über die App" or onto "Screenshots", the Website scrolls down. to the header, have u got an idea how to avoid that problem?

Strangely this only happens on Firefox and IE , not on Chrome?

Comment: Can you post minimal code/HTML/JS to find what the issue is?

Comment: cause of the # anchor on the link, when you click second time on link in google-chrome it scroll too

Comment: Sorry, but why the tinyurl? You're not gaining anything (the website it points to is just as short!) but you'll find a lot of people here who won't bother clicking on tinyurls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ok found you problem**

find that line in your page code

```
<div id="about" class="pane" style="display: block; "> <!-- Start About Page -->
```

*id="about"* in tag is causing this problem. this will be resolved if you change this id name
:)

Answer (score 1):

use focus() function of javascript to show div with class="header"
eg document.myform.mytextfield.focus(); to set the focus on click of button

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behaviour, considering that the link is anchored to a div on the same page:

```
<li><a href="#about">Über die App</a></li>

...

<div id="about" class="pane">
```

You can kill that behaviour like this (you have jQuery included on your page):

```
$(".tabs.page a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}):
```

...or just by removing the ID on the div.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your link is linking to #about (id="about"), the browser will try to go to that section displaying it in the top of your browser.

**Testing :**

User your browser and zoom into the button, then click on the link. You will see it will display the ABOUT content section with ID = about.

**Solution :**

Change ID's of the content

OR change hrefs of links

OR set a jquery event to prevent default browser actions.